# React Native | @react-native-community_picker is not resolved on android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using [React Native Boilerplate](https://github.com/keremcubuk/react-native-boilerplate) for my mobile application. This is the first time I'm running it. It is working fine on ios simulator but showing error on android emulator.

Below error is showing on while running `run-android`

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':@react-native-community_picker'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':@react-native- 
  community_picker:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
 Required by:
     project :@react-native-community_picker
  > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
     > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
           > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried installing this npm `@react-native-community/picker` and run again. It is not working.

packag.json

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/picker": "^1.6.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"immer": "^6.0.9",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-intl": "^2.8.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
"react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
"reselect": "^4.0.0"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated this npm [@react-native-community/picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/picker). It is working now.

updated Package.json

````
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "immer": "^6.0.9",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "native-base": "^2.13.13",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-intl": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0"```
````